# function to return an Interface

Tags: go

How come I can say that the result of CreateLion(), a pointer to a struct that implements the Cat interface, is an instance of the Cat interface, and yet I cannot say that CreateLion() is of type "function that returns the Cat interface."

What is the standard Golang approach to achieving this type of behavior?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var lion Cat := CreateLion()
    lion.Meow()

    // this line breaks. Why?
    var cf CatFactory = CreateLion
}

type Cat interface {
    Meow()
}

type Lion struct {}
func (l Lion) Meow() {
    fmt.Println("Roar")
}

// define a functor that returns a Cat interface
type CatFactory func() Cat

// define a function that returns a pointer to a Lion struct
func CreateLion() *Lion {
    return &Lion{}
}
```

Comment: Go is not Java. Go has no inheritance and no "is a" concept. Your attempt to model your problem looks like a direct translation from Java to Go. This will not work. Technically joy miao's answer is a complete and sensible explanation. Go is statically typed and a `*Lion` is not a `Cat`, even if a `*Lion` is assignable to a variable of type `Cat`; but assignability plays no role while matching type signatures. There is no need for factories in Go. Take a look at how the stdlib does things and stop writing Java code in Go.

Comment: Using a function as a type is not something that is unique to Java, @Volker.  This code is not translated from Java.

Comment: It works fine with a few changes: https://play.golang.org/p/ECSpoOIuzEx
It's not really a problem regarding inheritance.  Go has a smaller subject of OO constructs, just as Java has a smaller subset relative to C++

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cat interface {
    Meow()
}

type Lion struct{}

func (l Lion) Meow() {
    fmt.Println("Roar")
}

type CatFactory func() Cat

func CreateLion() Cat {
    return Lion{}
}

func main() {
    lion := CreateLion()
    lion.Meow()

    var cf CatFactory = CreateLion
    fLion := cf()
    fLion.Meow()
}
```

In most cases, you can assign any type to base type `interface{}`. But situation changes if type of function parameter is a `map[T]interface{}`, `[]interface{}` or `func() interface{}`.
In this case the type must be the same.

Comment: Sure your code might work but this is not a good answer, he is not seeking for working code, he wants an explanation.

Comment: In my use case, the Cat interface is defined in a separate go package that I do not wish to import into the go package where the Lion struct is defined. So I cannot just change the return type of the CreateLion function as you have suggested.

Comment: You can't assign func struct to func interface{}. Situation similar []interface{} - []struct. Because it's different types.

Comment: This answer is bad because now CreateLion returns a Cat, and you don't have access to any of the Lion-specific behaviors anymore. It makes sense for CatFactory to return a cat, but CreateLion should be returning a Lion.

Comment: CreateLion returns Lion) But interface of return value is a Cat (Lion is a big Cat)

Answer (score 6):

I think you should read this blog http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection,it is precise about the relation between variables,types and interfaces.

In your example `*Lion` is different with `Cat`.

You can correct function `CreateLion` returns from `*Lion` to `Cat`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that statically typed go differentiates the "this is a function that returns a cat" from "this is a function that returns a lion that is a cat" And therefore will not accept one as the other.

The way to fix this is to give your factory var exactly what it expects:

```
var cf CatFactory = func() Cat{
    return CreateLion()
}
catlion := cf()
catlion.Meow()
```

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn't need any special logic for the task you request, it will implicitly convert *Lion to interface Cat

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cat interface {
    Meow()
}

type Lion struct{}

func (l Lion) Meow() {
    fmt.Println("Roar")
}

func CreateLion() *Lion {
    return &Lion{}
}

func main() {
    var lion *Lion = CreateLion()
    lion.Meow()

    var cf Cat = CreateLion()
    cf.Meow()
}
```

Try it here: https://go.dev/play/p/PFp3fnXP8YH

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in the way that Go type system has been designed.

Using Liskov substitution principle, we can replace an expression of type `A` (expression which when evaluated will result in a value of type `A`) with an expression of type `B` **provided that** `B` is a subtype of `A`. We show this relation as `B < A`.

However, `B < A` does not automatically mean that `type func() B < type func() A` (although it makes sense).

The language designers have to decide how the language type constructors (func, slice, map, ...) handle the subtype relations. In case of Go, they decided to keep the `func` type constructor invariant with respect to its return type (and also its parameters).

Now, in your case you can address this by defining this subtype relationship yourself:

```golang
func AsCatFactory[Sub Cat](fn func() Sub) CatFactory {
    return func() Cat { return fn() }
}
// if you are on older Go versions without generics
func AsCatFactory(fn func() *Lion) CatFactory {
    return func() Cat { return fn() }
}
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```golang
    var cf CatFactory = AsCatFactory(CreateLion)
```

In this way, you have explicitly told the compiler that this substitution is safe. And you have done that because `*Lion` is a more specific return type than `Cat` which is in line with the following rule ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types)):

> It is safe to substitute a function f for a function g if f accepts a more general type of argument and returns a more specific type than g

Contrary to what other answers have said, a sound software engineering principle is that your return types should **always** be as specific as possible (aka Postel's Law). Therefore, `func CreateLion() *Lion` is completely correct.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine with a few changes.  Check it out here: https://play.golang.org/p/ECSpoOIuzEx

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    lion := CreateLion() // Go idomatic style recommends 
                         // allowing the compiler to divine the type
    lion.Meow()

    CatFactory := CreateLion
    _ = CatFactory // Go doesn't like unused variables and fails the build

    obj := CatFactory()     // exercising our factory method
    obj.Meow()
}

type Cat interface {
    Meow()
}

type Lion struct {}
func (l Lion) Meow() {
    fmt.Println("Roar")
}

// define a functor that returns a Cat interface
type CatFactory func() Cat

// define a function that returns a pointer to a Lion struct
func CreateLion() *Lion {
    return &Lion{}
}
```

Also, though Go doesn't have Java style interfaces, it does have interfaces and you can achieve polymorphism, but the types are known at compile time.

You can model an "Is A" relationship, if both types implement the same interface.  However it doesn't enforce the interface until you pass the object into a function that accepts that interface type.  So if you imagine implementing the Strategy pattern, when you're passing in the strategy object matching interface "Cat", that function will accept a "Lion" object, or any other class that implements a Meow function with the correct signature.

Also, factory methods are definitely necessary and useful in Go.  In fact, instead of constructors, in Go, you use factory functions to construct your objects.

Comment: `func CreateLion() Lion {return Lion{}}` also works. Great answer +1.

Comment: You are just shading the variable/type. Just remove the `type CatFactory func () Cat`. It is not used in your code.